# Client-Side Validation Interfering with Server-Side Redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin (http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/) to validate data on the client-side. If all goes well, the user is to be directed to another page when he hits submit. This works just fine if I comment out the plug-in script section, but does not when it is included.

I am a bit perplexed honestly. I do not get a 'headers already sent' message, and I thought the plug-in would stop from ever even going to the server if the data was invalid - meaning that it should make on a bit of difference to the PHP if it is included or not.

What am I missing?

the beginning of my main PHP page

```
require('scripts/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
include('header.php');
$ssn = $_SESSION['userSSN'];
$last = $_SESSION['userLast'];
if($_SESSION['verified']) {
$verified = true;
}

//  CODE OMITTED... //

$mailer = new PHPMailer;

$mailer->addAddress("insurance@insurancemidam.com");
$mailer->addAttachment($zipName); 
$mailer->Subject = "Insurance Enrollment";
$mailer->Body = "Testing";

if(!$mailer->send()) {
echo "<h2>Error Submitting form. Please check your input and try again</h2>";
} else {
unlink($zipName);
header("Location:success.php");
}
}
```

the tail end of my main PHP

```
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submitInsurance' value='Submit' /></form>";
    } 
include('footer.php');

?>
<script>

$("#mainForm").validate({
submit: {

    settings: {
    errorListContainer: '.formGroup',
     }
    }
});
```

footer.php

```
<?php

echo "</div><footer>Copyright Mid-America Hotels Corporation " . date("Y") . "</footer></html>";
```

header.php

```
<?php

session_start();
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('includes.php');


$host = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';

$db = new dataBaseAccess($host, $user, $pass);

// if user is attempting to login...
if(!isset($_POST['submitInsurance'])) {
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
$user = formatInput($_POST['user']);
$ssn = formatInput($_POST['ssn']);
if($db->verifyUser($user, $ssn, 'insurance_validation'))  {
$_SESSION['verified'] = true;
$_SESSION['userLast'] = $user;
$_SESSION['userSSN'] = $ssn; 
header('Location: insurance.php');

}
else {
echo "<!doctype html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/base.css' /><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='scripts/validation.js'><script src='scripts/base.js'></script><title>Insurance Mid-Am</title></head><body><header><img src='logo.png' alt='Mid-America Hotels'><h1>Insurance Enrollment</h1></header><div id='mainContent'><h2 class='error'>Invalid Login Credentials!</h2>";
} 
}
else {
echo "<!doctype html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/base.css' /><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='scripts/validation.js'></script><script src='scripts/base.js'></script><title>Insurance Mid-Am</title></head><body><header><img src='logo.png' alt='Mid-America Hotels'><h1>Insurance Enrollment</h1></header><div id='mainContent'>";
}
}

?>
```

EDIT: The reason is that, for some reason, $_POST['submitInsurance'] is not getting sent. Using var_dump, it appears the other data gets sent, but the button's value. Why might this be?

Comment: I don't know if you want people on your database, so you might want to remove your credentials (located header.php).

Comment: Oh, I cannot believe I did that. Thank you so so much for pointing that out.